# Colouring certain data in a column

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am sending some data over to the html template, which is located on a certain server. Template accepts data and fills out an pdf document, which I've implemented in .js. How can I colour every data in a certain column?

Currently I have template from some other data export example, and right now it just fills data with certain header, according to types from js.

Order of photos:

template:
[html template, the part where template fills table with data)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6oBXZ.png)

data that I send to server from .js:
[Example from js. of data that I send over into template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D4Tfw.png)

Current example of how exported PDF looks like:
[example of how it looks right now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XjBeR.png)

I want to fill number 176 with yellow. And not just this exact cell, I want every data from that column coloured with yellow. So column with header: "Letni fond".

Comment: Please update your question to include a [mcve]

Comment: Hey Jan, please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and update your question. This way, it'll be easier for us to help you.